# Special character length

Tags: c, special-characters

I found something really strange today.

In the code above, I saw that `utrlen(&eot)` (utrlen == strlen) is equal to two, and `utrlen(&etx) == 1`.

The best part : when I swap the order of declaration with etx, `utrlen(&eot) == 1` and `utrlen(&etx) == 2`...

```
char            **get_ukey_string()
{
  static char   eot = 0x4;
  static char   etx = 0x3;
  static char   *ukey_string[NB_UKEY] = {
    "\b", "\r", "[B", "\0", "\n", "[D", "[C", "[A", &etx, &eot
  };

  return (ukey_string);
}

t_hashtable     *new_ukey_htable(int fd)
{
  char          **ukey_string;
  t_hashtable   *htable;
  t_hashnode    *hnode;
  char          *key;
  unsigned int  i;
  size_t        size;

  if ((htable = new_hashtable(NB_UKEY)) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  ukey_string = get_ukey_string();
  i = 2;
  while (i < NB_UKEY + 2)
    {
      key = ukey_string[i - 2];
      size = utrlen(key);
      if (((hnode = new_hashnode(sutrdup(key, size), size, i)) == NULL)
          || htable->add_node(htable, hnode))
        {
          delete_hashtable(htable);
          return (NULL);
        }
      ++i;
    }
  return (htable);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: `strlen` needs a null-terminated string. A pointer to a character is not a null-terminated string, and your program could find the next zero byte anywhere; it just so happens that you end up with the two characters consecutive in memory (probably) followed by a zero.

Comment: Why are you using `utrlen` rather than `strlen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eot and etx are char, not char *, so you can't apply strlen on them because there are no null terminator.

Comment: I just want to say : omg...
Sorry for this question, i think i need some spleep ^^"
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The `strlen` function (why are you calling it `utrlen`?) takes an argument of type `const char*`. That argument must point to the initial character of a *string*, defined as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character".

Calling `strlen` with the address of a declared `char` object is legal; the address type `char*` (pointer to `char`) matches the required type to be passed to `strlen`. But it's not the initial character of a *string*, so the behavior is undefined.

In practice, `strlen` will start at the `char` object whose address you gave it, and iterate until it sees a null character `'\0'`.

If the `char` object happens to have the value `'\0'`, it finds it immediately and returns `0` -- which is not particularly useful.

If it has some other value, `strlen` will attempt to scan bytes in memory that aren't part of the object. The result is undefined behavior.

Don't do that.